# Can I rent and drive in Georgia (Country) with a UAE driving license?

Tags: indian-citizens, driving-licenses, uae, georgia-country

I am going to travel to [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)), (the country, not the US state) for a week and want to know if I can rent and drive a car there. I hold a valid driving license from the UAE and an Indian license as well.

I know that people who have a resident UAE Visa can travel to Georgia visa free but am wondering if I should get an International driving license from the UAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Markhoos Initiative](https://moi.gov.ae/en/About.MOI/content/markhoos.initiative.aspx) from the UAE Ministry of Interior lists the countries that recognise the UAE Drivers' License

> Recognition: Use of the UAE drivers license  for nationals for purposes other that the residency. The possibility for UAE visitors to use the national drivers license for purposes other than the residency.

Georgia is not on that list. You will therefore need to apply for a IDP

The [Automobile and Touring club of the UAE](https://www.atcuae.ae/idl-international-driving-license/) states that you also need an IDP